# how do I write <br> in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, line, break

Hi I want insert break line tag in javascript and tried everything from stackowerflow,but nothing helped me.
Here is my [github repo for.js file](https://github.com/Turashviliguro/d2symbols/blob/main/script.js) and I need make breakline between line 204 and 205 like this .
I mean need third section under second one ,check it here [turashviliguro.github.io/d2symbols](https://turashviliguro.github.io/d2symbols/)
I will be happy if you help me.

```js
"Seals": [
                new Glyph(0xE076, "Stasis: Glyph 0", Colors.STASIS),
                new Glyph(0xE077, "Stasis: Glyph 1", Colors.STASIS),
                new Glyph(0xE078, "Stasis: Glyph 2", Colors.STASIS),
                new Glyph(0xE079, "Stasis: Glyph 3", Colors.STASIS)
            ],
            <need breakline here>
            "Other": [
                new Glyph(0xE052, "Light", Colors.EXPERIENCE),
                new Glyph(0xE059, "Settings"),
                new Glyph(0xE147, "Gilded", Colors.GILDED_FG, Colors.GILDED_BG),
                new Glyph(0xE148, "Cabal Gold", Colors.LEGENDARY_LABEL),
                 new Glyph(0xE142, "Headshot")

            ],
```

Comment: I dont know what these Glyphs are but have you tried to insert an empty array?

Comment: Would like to know why you want to insert `<br>` in javascript, you can do that in html

Comment: no, U can't insert a br to an object.

Comment: So you want 3 columns: 1) combat, 2) character + controller underneath, 3) keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a grid that looks like this:

```
| COMBAT | CHARACTER  | KEYBOARD |
|        | CONTROLLER |          |
```

[image]

Than you can try this:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

main>section:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

main>section:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1;
}

main>section:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

main>section:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean, but to simulate the html br tag you can use "\n" in your string.

Comment: This not helped.
I mean need third section under second one ,check it here https://turashviliguro.github.io/d2symbols/